# NavigationItem LeftBarButtonItem Custome View Auto Layaut

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set a costume navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem from a nib, but i get an weird behaviour in landscape.

EDIT:

To be clear the view contains a button and a label,this is why i am using a costume view, both button and label have constraints.

```
self.buttonView =//init;
[self.buttonView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 36)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.buttonView];

[self.buttonView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
//you will see why
```

[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

Comment: You can add an autolayout constraint for width in Interface Builder since you are already using nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only workaround i could find asap, if someone have a better idea please feel free to share

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    [self setMenuButtonFrame];

}

-(void)setMenuButtonFrame
{
    self.menuView.frame = CGRectMake(self.menuView.frame.origin.x,     
    self.menuView.frame.origin.y, 
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height-8, 
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height-8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that autolayout is trying to satisfy some constraints thus its expanding your button's frame.

To fix this set the contentHugging priority to required for your button:

```
[self.buttonView setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Try that and let me know if it works

Comment: Tried, but still the same behaviour